# Synchronization Event with awaitAny

Tags: java, multithreading, event-handling, synchronization

In Java, there is no way I know of to wait for multiple events at the same time (see [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265225/java-how-can-a-thread-wait-on-multiple-objects)). Since I would like to use that feature (similar to [`WaitForMultipleObjects()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in the Win32 API), I decided to write my own event class that includes this feature. While the class is pretty straight-forward, thread synchronization always has some hidden pitfalls. I would like to uncover those, if any are present.

For some more specific questions:

- Are there any possible deadlocks, race conditions, data races or other bugs present in the code?
- Is the synchronization sufficient, or should `bSignaled` be made volatile?
- Are there redundant checks or other things reducing the performance of the code?
- Is there a library class that I have missed, offering the same functionality?

```
public class Event
{
    private boolean bSignaled = false;

    private static final Object anySignaler = new Object();

    /**
     * Wait for the event to signal. If the event has been signaled before,
     * return immediately.
     */
    public void await() throws InterruptedException
    {
        if (!bSignaled) {
            synchronized (this) {
                while (!bSignaled) {
                    this.wait();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Signal the event. This notifies all threads that are waiting for this 
     * event to occur, as well as all threads that are waiting for any event.
     */
    public void signal()
    {
        bSignaled = true;
        sendNotify(this);
        sendNotify(anySignaler);
    }

    /**
     * Helper function that calls notifiyAll() inside a locked block.
     */
    private static final void sendNotify(Object lock)
    {
        synchronized (lock) {
            lock.notifyAll();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Return the signaled state of this event.
     */
    public boolean isSignaled()
    {
        return bSignaled;
    }



    /**
     * @see Event#awaitAll(Event[])
     */
    public static void awaitAll(Event ev0,Event ... events) throws InterruptedException
    {
        ev0.await();
        for (Event e: events) e.await();
    }

    /**
     * @see Event#awaitAll(Event[])
     */
    public static void awaitAll(List<Event> events) throws InterruptedException
    {
        for (Event e: events) e.await();
    }

    /**
     * Wait until all events have been signaled.
     */
    public static void awaitAll(Event[] events) throws InterruptedException
    {
            for (Event e: events) e.await();
    }

    /**
     * @see Event#awaitAny(Event[])
     */
    public static int awaitAny(Event ev0,Event ... events) throws InterruptedException
    {
        Event[] array = new Event[events.length+1];
        array[0] = ev0;
        if (events.length > 0) System.arraycopy(events,0,array,1,events.length);
        return awaitAny(array);
    }

    /**
     * @see Event#awaitAny(Event[])
     */
    public static int awaitAny(List<Event> events) throws InterruptedException
    {
        return awaitAny(events.toArray(new Event[events.size()]));
    }

    /**
     * Wait until any of the given events have been signaled. If any of the
     * events have already been signaled, return immediately.
     * @return the index of the event that was first found to be signaled.
     */
    public static int awaitAny(Event[] events) throws InterruptedException
    {
        int res = checkSignals(events);
        if (res < 0) {
            synchronized (anySignaler) {
                while ((res = checkSignals(events)) < 0) {
                    anySignaler.wait();
                }
            }
        }
        return res;
    }

    /**
     * Helper function to check if any of the events has been signaled.
     * @return the index of the first signaled event found,
     *         or -1 if no event was signaled.
     */
    private static int checkSignals(Event[] events)
    {
        int len = events.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (events[i].isSignaled()) return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, you should use one, and only one synchronization strategy in any class. You have synchronization, and are contemplating volatiles too.

The best-practice mechanism for now in Java is using the classes from `java.util.concurrent.*` to manage locking, and memory synchronization. The benefit from there that will help you most, is the Condition concept, as well as the fine-grained management of locks.

Your locking at the moment relies on a 'global' lock that all events use, thus if you have many collections of events running, each collection uses the same lock. Thus, if some other Events are happening in some other code block somewhere, we will still be notified or each of those 'remote' event completions, and our completions will notify their awaits....

Additionally, I did not like the way you manage the await-any concept. You literally scan the Events for changes, and check for one to complete.

In essence, I dislike:

1. using a static `lock`
2. using synchronization
3. using messy awaitAny logic

Finally, I did not like the method you chose as the core await container... Instead of the `awaitAll(Event[])` I prefer the `awaitAll(List<Event>...)`. I cannot defend that preference right now though. Not sure why I prefer it.

Still, having thrown all that criticism at you, here's how I would probably do it. Note, the logic change for the await....

You have a single static lock. What I suggest is to create a 'completion listener'. In the case of awaitAll, each Event has it's own listener. In the case of awaitAny, they all share a single listener, so there's just one notification.

The system below makes each `await*(...)` an independent operation. The only signals are what's happening that's relevant to the completion service.

This is untested, so go through and understand it well ;-)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class Event {

    private static final class EventCompletion {
        private final Lock plock = new ReentrantLock();
        private final Condition pcond = plock.newCondition();
        private boolean complete = false;

        void completed() {
            plock.lock();
            try {
                if (!complete) {
                    complete = true;
                    pcond.signalAll();
                }
            } finally {
                plock.unlock();
            }
        }

        void awaitCompletion() throws InterruptedException {
            plock.lock();
            try {
                while (!complete) {
                    pcond.await();
                }
            } finally {
                plock.unlock();
            }
        }


    }

    private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private boolean complete = false;

    private final List<EventCompletion> listeners = new ArrayList<>();

    private void addListener(EventCompletion ec) {
        boolean notifyNow = false;
        lock.lock();
        try {
            if (!complete) {
                listeners.add(ec);
            } else {
                notifyNow = true;
            }
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
        if (notifyNow) {
            // immediate notification of completion...
            ec.completed();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Return the signaled state of this Event.
     */
    public boolean isSignaled() {
        lock.lock();
        try {
           return complete;
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Return the signaled state of this Event.
     */
    public void signal() {
        EventCompletion[] toNotify = null;
        lock.lock();
        try {
            if (complete) {
                return;
            }
            toNotify = listeners.toArray(new EventCompletion[listeners.size()]);
            listeners.clear(); // no need to remember previous notifications....
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
        for (EventCompletion ec : toNotify) {
            ec.completed();
        }
    }

    public static void awaitAll(Event ev0, Event... events) throws InterruptedException {
        List<Event> toWait = new ArrayList<>(1 + events.length);
        toWait.add(ev0);
        for (Event e : events) {
            toWait.add(e);
        }
        awaitAll(toWait);
    }

    public static void awaitAll(Event[] events) throws InterruptedException {
        awaitAll(Arrays.asList(events));
    }

    public static void awaitAll(List<Event> events) throws InterruptedException {
        EventCompletion[] toComplete = new EventCompletion[events.size()];
        int pos = 0;
        for (Event e : events) {
            EventCompletion ec = new EventCompletion();
            e.addListener(ec);
            toComplete[pos++] = ec;
        }

        for (EventCompletion ec : toComplete) {
            ec.awaitCompletion();
        }

    }

    public static int awaitAny(Event ev0, Event... events) throws InterruptedException {
        List<Event> toWait = new ArrayList<>(1 + events.length);
        toWait.add(ev0);
        for (Event e : events) {
            toWait.add(e);
        }
        return awaitAny(toWait);
    }

    public static int awaitAny(Event[] events) throws InterruptedException {
        return awaitAny(Arrays.asList(events));
    }

    public static int awaitAny(List<Event> events) throws InterruptedException {
        // all events notify the same completion service.
        EventCompletion ec = new EventCompletion();
        for (Event e : events) {
            e.addListener(ec);
        }
        ec.awaitCompletion();
        int pos = 0;
        for (Event e : events) {
            if (e.isSignaled()) {
                // first completed event is returned.
                return pos;
            }
            pos++;
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("One of the events must have been signalled... This Exception should never happen!");

    }

}
```

---

**Update:** As per your comment, the use of ReentrantLock and Condition is not necessary. I prefer to use consistent locking mechanisms in my code, and I have 'standardized' on Locks. Locks can do anything synchronization can do, and then more too. Unless you have many thousands of events all happening at once, the memory cost of the locks would be negligible.

Still, I agree with the sentiment you expressed. The same can be done with synchronization:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Event {

    /* Private class can be used as a synchronization lock too */
    private static final class EventCompletion {
        private boolean complete = false;

        synchronized void completed() {
            if (!complete) {
                complete = true;
                this.notifyAll();
            }
        }

        synchronized void awaitCompletion() throws InterruptedException {
            while (!complete) {
                this.wait();
            }
        }


    }

    private boolean complete = false;

    // use private-final listeners class as private lock on public class.
    private final List<EventCompletion> listeners = new ArrayList<>();

    private void addListener(EventCompletion ec) {
        boolean notifyNow = false;
        synchronized (listeners) {
            if (!complete) {
                listeners.add(ec);
            } else {
                notifyNow = true;
            }
        }
        if (notifyNow) {
            // immediate notification of completion...
            ec.completed();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Return the signaled state of this Event.
     */
    public boolean isSignaled() {
        synchronized(listeners) {
           return complete;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Return the signaled state of this Event.
     */
    public void signal() {
        EventCompletion[] toNotify = null;
        synchronized(listeners) {
            if (complete) {
                return;
            }
            toNotify = listeners.toArray(new EventCompletion[listeners.size()]);
            listeners.clear(); // no need to remember previous notifications....
        }
        for (EventCompletion ec : toNotify) {
            ec.completed();
        }
    }

    public static void awaitAll(Event ev0, Event... events) throws InterruptedException {
        List<Event> toWait = new ArrayList<>(1 + events.length);
        toWait.add(ev0);
        for (Event e : events) {
            toWait.add(e);
        }
        awaitAll(toWait);
    }

    public static void awaitAll(Event[] events) throws InterruptedException {
        awaitAll(Arrays.asList(events));
    }

    public static void awaitAll(List<Event> events) throws InterruptedException {
        EventCompletion[] toComplete = new EventCompletion[events.size()];
        int pos = 0;
        for (Event e : events) {
            EventCompletion ec = new EventCompletion();
            e.addListener(ec);
            toComplete[pos++] = ec;
        }

        for (EventCompletion ec : toComplete) {
            ec.awaitCompletion();
        }

    }

    public static int awaitAny(Event ev0, Event... events) throws InterruptedException {
        List<Event> toWait = new ArrayList<>(1 + events.length);
        toWait.add(ev0);
        for (Event e : events) {
            toWait.add(e);
        }
        return awaitAny(toWait);
    }

    public static int awaitAny(Event[] events) throws InterruptedException {
        return awaitAny(Arrays.asList(events));
    }

    public static int awaitAny(List<Event> events) throws InterruptedException {
        // all events notify the same completion service.
        EventCompletion ec = new EventCompletion();
        for (Event e : events) {
            e.addListener(ec);
        }
        ec.awaitCompletion();
        int pos = 0;
        for (Event e : events) {
            if (e.isSignaled()) {
                // first completed event is returned.
                return pos;
            }
            pos++;
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("One of the events must have been signalled... This Exception should never happen!");

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Using an event listener is definitely the right thing to do, I'll think about how to do it without decreasing performance when most waits only wait for a single event.

Comment: About the use of `ReentrantLock` and `Condition` - why would that be a good idea? From what I can see, that uses two additional objects per Event for no gain (synchronized on this does the same). Do those classes have an advantage over the built-in feature?

Comment: @Thalur - My preference would be to use Locks, but for reasons that may not apply to you. I have updated my answer with a synchronization-only version too.